# Android removing navigation menu item highlighting

Tags: android

When you click a menu item in my navigation drawer, it becomes slightly darker and remains that way until another item is clicked. I'm trying to keep it the same colour no matter what state it's in.

Is it some kind of overlay? I've think I've covered all possible states in drawer_items.xml.
How do I prevent this behaviour?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  .
  .
  android:background="@drawable/drawer_items"
  .
  app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**drawer_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_activated="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_selected="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_focused="true"  />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:id="@+id/arbitrary_id_1">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_24dp"
        android:title="Try Again/Refresh" />
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:id="@+id/arbitrary_id_2">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fast_rewind_24dp"
        android:title="Go Back" />
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:id="@+id/arbitrary_id_3">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_3" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: post your `activity_main_drawer`

Comment: Maybe your problem comes from code in the activity and not from xml, can you post your code?

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you can use something like this,
to prevent item from changing its color when clicked, you can try to change in `activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
```

to

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="none">
```

Or you can do this way:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_item_one"
        android:title="Item One"/>
    ...
  </group>
```

To:

```
<item>
    <menu>
      ...
      <item
        android:id="@+id/item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_item_one"
        android:title="Item One"/>
      ...
    </menu>
  </item>
```

Read more at [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Answer (score 5):

So the `NavigationView` is highlighted based on the `colorControlHighlight` property. You could create a theme for your drawer and make it transparent:

```
<style name="Drawer" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0000</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Drawer" />
```

Comment: you can add this item too
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

Answer (score 4):

Try to implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in your activity
and force `return false`:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
     when (item.itemId) { 
      }

return false
```

As the doc says:

```
/**
 * Called when an item in the navigation menu is selected.
 *
 * @param item The selected item
 *
 * @return true to display the item as the selected item
 */
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to make all the states to **false** in **drawer_items.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_activated="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_selected="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_focused="false"  />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_checked="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```